Launch Flatpak after Waking from Sleep
This askUbuntu post explains the correct way to execute a script on resume from suspend with systemd. You just place a script like this sleep-initiate.sh in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/:
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

case "$1" in
    pre)
            #code execution BEFORE sleeping/hibernating/suspending
    ;;
    post)
            #code execution AFTER resuming
            sleep 10
            /usr/bin/flatpak run com.google.Chrome
    ;;
esac

exit 0

I've gotten it to work with simple Linux commands, but it will not work launching Flatpaks as shown above. Why? Is it something to do with the Flatpak environment not being ready immediately upon my computer waking from sleep?

Did you check whether /usr/bin/flatpak run com.google.Chrome correctly works on a regular terminal? Also, switching to the official google chrome installer (instead of flatpak) might help

@Archisman Panigrahi the command does work correctly in the terminal.
